# KSH : How to convert integer to date and add Minutes to it, in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have a numeric value N1 = 20170708192012, and want to convert to date
something like : 
D1=`echo $N1 | date -d '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`
echo $D1

post conversion add 40 Minutes to get new Date.

Comment: `date` can't parse the date in that format. Is `awk` an acceptable option?

Comment: @randomir , yes awk can be an option

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the string before passing it to date and so:

```
 N1=$(awk '{ print substr($0,1,8)" "substr($0,9,2)":"substr($0,11,2)":"substr($0,13,2)}' <<< 20170708192012)
```

Use awk and the substr function to build N1 in a format acceptable to date.

Answer (score 0):

If your `awk` supports [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions) `mktime` and `strftime` (which are a GNU extension), you can first convert the input string into a Unix timestamp (by manually splitting and using `mktime`), and then format the output with `strftime`:

```
N1=20170708192012
D1=$(awk '{ print strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", mktime(substr($0,1,4)" "substr($0,5,2)" "substr($0,7,2)" "substr($0,9,2)" "(substr($0,11,2)+40)" "substr($0,13,2))) }' <<<"$N1")
```

Note that `mktime` accepts dates only in `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS"` format, that's why we need to construct it manually. But **it does the normalization automatically**, and it will happily convert `"2017 1 1 0 80 0"` to the same timestamp as `"2017 1 1 1 20 0"`. That's why we can simply add `40` to minutes from the input and get the correct output.

For your input, we get:

```
echo $D1
20170708200012
```